# Clustering before regression - recommender system

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a file called train.dat which has three fields - `userID`, `movieID` and `rating`.

I need to predict the `rating` in the test.dat file based on this.

I want to know how I can use scikit-learn's KMeans to group similar users given that I have only feature - `rating`. 
Does this even make sense to do? After the clustering step, I could do a regression step to get the ratings for each user-movie pair in test.dat

Edit: I have some extra files which contain the actors in each movie, the directors and also the genres that the movie falls into. I'm unsure how to use these to start with and I'm asking this question because I was wondering whether it's possible to get a simple model working with just rating and then enhance it with the other data. I read that this is called content based recommendation. I'm sorry, I should've written about the other data files as well.

Answer (score 0):

scikit-learn **is not** a library for recommender systems, neither is kmeans typical tool for clustering such data. Things that you are trying to do deal with graphs, and usually are either analyzed on graph level, or using various matrix factorization techniques.

In particular kmeans only works in euclidean spaces, and you do not have such thing here. What you can do is to use DBScan (or any other clustering technique accepting arbitrary simialrity, but this one is actually in scikit-learn) and define similarity between two users by some kind of their agreement in terms of their taste, for example:

```
sim(user1, user2) = # movies both users like / # movies at least one of them likes
```

which is known as Jaccard coefficient for similarity between binary vectors. You have rating, not just "liking" but I am giving here a simplest possible example, while you can come up with dozens other things to try out. The point is - for the simplest approach all you have to do is define a notion of per-user similarity and apply clustering that accepts such a setting (like mentioned DBScan).

Answer (score -1):

Clustering users makes sense. But if your only feature is the rating, I don't think it could produce a useful model for prediction. Below are my assumptions to make this justification:

- The quality of movie should be distributed with a gaussion distribution.
- If we look at the rating distribution of a common user, it should be something like gaussian.
- I don't exclude the possibility that a few users only give ratings when they see a bad movie (thus all low ratings); and vice versa. But on a large scale of users, this should be unusual behavior.

Thus I can imagine that after clustering, you get small groups of users in the two extreme cases; and most users are in the middle (because they share the gaussian-like rating behavior). Using this model, you probably get good results for users in the two small (extreme) groups; however for the majority of users, you cannot expect good predictions.

Comment: how marginal distributions imply that clustering will not matter? Recommendation is much more local problem, and nearly no arguments regarding marginal distribution - matter. I completely agree with the main claim here, but justification does not seem to fit the situation.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I am aware of the importance of "local". But I might mis-understand how the op is going to do this clustering. Because the op mentioned that the only feature is the rating, there is no association between a user and a movie. How the "local" benefit can be used here? Can you give me an example that clustering with "rating" can produce interesting groups (except the two extreme cases I mentioned).

Comment: "rating" is a relation between user and a movie, this is not a number for a user, it is a number (label) for the relation between user and a movie. At least this is a typical meaning of "rating" in recomendation systems. Efficiently this means that you have a graph with 2 types of nodes - users and movies, and labeled edges between one group and another. There are hundreads possible ways of clustering such graphs, which have arbitrary complexity. There is nothing in marginal distributions making it hard.

Comment: As a trivial example - users that like horrors vs ones that like comedies can create 2 clusters, and even if after marginalization everything is gaussian - this small clusters will have completely different (conditional) distributions.

Comment: but the op said that the only feature is rating, how do you get horrors or other genres? ( i assume you have only user id and rating). He did not said we can use movie id in the clustering.

Comment: you are not using genre in clustering, I am saying such clusters can **emerge** since there is clearly a completely different conditional distribution, and you might be able to find it. movie id is in data, read begining of the question, data is of form "userID, movieID and rating", thus you have a relation "userID rated movieID with rating". This is a perfectly fine, typical setting for recommender system.

Comment: If we are allowed to use movie id, definitely this is doable. I agree with all your comments.